# How could reading numbers using sscanf crash?

Tags: c++, cppcheck

Cppcheck has detected a potential problem in a code like this:

```
float a, b, c;
int count = sscanf(data, "%f,%f,%f", &a, &b, &c);
```

It says that: "scanf without field width limits can crash with huge data". How is that possible? Is that a known bug in some sscanf implementations? I understand that the numbers may overflow (numerically), but how could the program crash? Is that a false positive in cppcheck?

I have found a similar question: [scanf Cppcheck warning](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7022468/scanf-cppcheck-warning), but the answer is not completely satisfying. The answer mentions type safety, but that should not be an issue here.

Comment: Try sscanf_s instead. As normal scanf, sscanf is not overflow safe.

Comment: @guitarflow: The problem is that I don't see where it may overflow.

Comment: @guitarflow Or don’t. `sscanf_s` isn’t portable and also not actually safe, despite what the name suggests and Microsoft claims.

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Format_string_attack is also important to pay attention to. Buffer overflows alone aren't the only vulnerabilities in scans. If you allow the user to input the format string they can use %x to print arbitrary memory locations and %n to write them. Among other things.

Comment: @synthesizerpatel: As you can see, format is a string literal here, so that is not a problem.

Comment: Yes, in this particular case perhaps. But, thats the problem with static code analysis - you get a lot of false positives. I try to avoid scanf just because whoever inherits my code might not know what the boundaries of safety are. But, thats just me.

Comment: @KonradRudolph Really? I knew that it isn't portable but I didn't know about the potential danger. What makes it unsafe?

Comment: @JurajBlaho Check this out http://crasseux.com/books/ctutorial/sscanf.html#sscanf

Comment: @guitarflow Well it presupposes that you already know the buffer size. but this is usually the issue in the first place. `sscanf_s` doesn’t actually check (and cannot check) whether the buffer size is correct. So it protects only insofar as it makes the buffer size explicit. A far superior method is preventing buffer overflows in the first place, and C++ makes this trivial. (Also, at least one of the “safe” commands – but I don’t remember which – had a buffer overflow bug. Oh the irony.)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I am a Cppcheck developer.

Yes this is a weird crash. With "huge data" it means millions of digits.

If you use the --verbose flag then cppcheck will actually write a little example code that usually crashes on linux computers.

Here is an example code that crashes with a segmentation fault on my Ubuntu 11.10 computer:

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define HUGE_SIZE 100000000

int main()
{
    int i;
    char *data = new char[HUGE_SIZE];
    for (int i = 0; i < HUGE_SIZE; ++i)
        data[i] = '1';
    data[HUGE_SIZE-1] = 0;
    sscanf(data, "%i", &i);
    delete [] data;
    return 0;
}
```

For your info I don't get a crash when I try this example code on visual studio.

I used g++ version 4.6.1 to compile.

Comment: The question remains. Why does it crash? I don't see any reason when the code to parse the number could be something like: `for each digit in data: result*=10; result+=digit`. How could that crash? Why is it not fixed?

Comment: I primarily wanted to answer "Is that a false positive in Cppcheck?". It is a weird crash so it's easy to think so. I can't answer why technically it crashes. It has been a known and widespread problem for years. I agree that with your code it can't crash so obviously that is not how the data is parsed.

Comment: Yes, I understand. Thanks at least for a partial answer. I gave you +1.

Answer (score 4):

The segmentation fault seems to be a bug in glibc.

I've just tested this with a similar program, which crashes in ubuntu 10.04,
but works in ubuntu 12.04.

As Daniel Marjamäki said, his program crashes in 11.10, I believe the bug is
fixed in between.

Answer (score 1):

OK, consider this code:

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    const char* data = "9999999999999999999999999.9999999999999999999999//i put alot more 9's there, this just to get the point through
    float a;
    int count = sscanf(data, "%f", &a);
    printf("%f",a);
}
```

the output of this program is "inf" - no crash. And I put a huge amounts of 9's there. So I suspect Cppcheck is just plain wrong about this.

Comment: Which compilers did you check this with?

Comment: compiled with just g++. why, did you get a different result with another compiler?

Comment: Not yet, but I feel that the conclusion "CppCheck is just plain wrong" may be a bit premature when testing on just 1 compiler. (I can only test with VC++2005 where I'm sitting now, sorry.)

Comment: Have you tried the sample posted by Daniel Marjamäki in your compiler?